# error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`

Tags: react-native, android-studio

error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
that is the fault when i tried react-native run-android
and also
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Could not determine the dependencies of null. > SDK location not found. Define a valid SDK location with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'D:\React_Dowland\VS_App\mobile_app\android\local.properties'. * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BU�LD FAILED
what is the problem? i could not solve it

what is the problem? i could not solve it

Comment: Posting an error message without it being formatted for easy reading, without context as to what led to the error, is insufficient for anyone to give a reasonable response.

Answer (score 0):

as I can see, this is a misconfiguration of your environment:

Please take a look at the official documentation:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?os=windows&platform=android